# how to get value exists in two separate lists using python

Tags: python, django

Compare two lists and find duplicate that exist in both lists
from two lists remove the existing duplicates and create new lists.

```
Input 
a=  [
"DJI_0229.jpg",
"DJI_0232.jpg",
"DJI_0233.jpg"
"DJI_0235.jpg"
]
b= [
"DJI_0229.jpg",
"DJI_0232.jpg",
"DJI_0233.jpg"
"DJI_0230.jpg",
"DJI_0231.jpg",
"DJI_0234.jpg"
]
```

```
output = 
[
"DJI_0230.jpg",
"DJI_0231.jpg",
"DJI_0234.jpg",
"DJI_0235.jpg"
]
```

Comment: You want to remove duplicates values ?

Comment: Show your own effort as properly formatted code in the question.

Comment: I want to remove duplicate values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do this

```
a= ["DJI_0229.jpg","DJI_0232.jpg","DJI_0233.jpg","DJI_0235.jpg"]
b= ["DJI_0229.jpg","DJI_0232.jpg","DJI_0233.jpg","DJI_0230.jpg","DJI_0231.jpg","DJI_0234.jpg"]
c = []
for image in (a+b):
    if image not in c:
        c.append(image)
    else:
        c.remove(image)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
def remove_dupilicate(List1,List2):
    return [item for item in List1 if item not in List2]

new_a = remove_dupilicate(a, b)
new_b = remove_dupilicate(b, a)
print(new_a,new_b)
```

output for new_a list is `['DJI_0235.jpg']` and new_b list is `['DJI_0230.jpg', 'DJI_0231.jpg', 'DJI_0234.jpg']`

Answer (score 0):

The most simplest way to achieve what you want is using symmetric difference of sets. Consider the below venn diagram :

[image: Venn diagram for symmetric difference of 2 sets]

Code implementation

```
from pprint import pprint

a = ["DJI_0229.jpg", "DJI_0232.jpg", "DJI_0233.jpg", "DJI_0235.jpg"]

b = [
    "DJI_0229.jpg",
    "DJI_0232.jpg",
    "DJI_0233.jpg",
    "DJI_0230.jpg",
    "DJI_0231.jpg",
    "DJI_0234.jpg",
]

final_list = sorted(
    list(
        set(a).symmetric_difference(set(b))  # Using some maths :-)
    )  # Converting the set to list
)  # Sorting the resultant list

pprint(final_list)
```